# Python SortedSet ValueError when using discard

Tags: python, valueerror, sortedset

I am using [SortedSet](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) to store objects in sorted order. I keep getting ValueError object not in list even though the object is indeed in the list.

Here is a reproducible example

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedSet

a = SortedSet()

class example:
    def __init__(self,p, id):
        self.p = p
        self.id = id
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.p < other.p
 


a.add(example(5, 1))
x = example(5, 2)
a.add(x)

if x in a:
    print("found")
    a.discard(x)
```

In this example "found" is printed and I get `ValueError: <__main__.example object at 0x7fc19ebb2400> not in list`

I have been trying to figure out why this is failing for hours now and I would really appreciate any help.

Edit:
Here is the complete traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/CLD/clockwork-rl/work/Clockwork-RL/temp.py", line 18, in <module>
    a.discard(x)
  File "/home/salzayat/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sortedcontainers/sortedset.py", line 422, in discard
    self._list.remove(value)
  File "/home/salzayat/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.py", line 462, in remove
    raise ValueError('{0!r} not in list'.format(value))
ValueError: <__main__.example object at 0x7f3783488400> not in list
```

Edit2:

I updated the code to fix the missing return and still produce the error.

I now understand that I need to add a condition for the `id` as well. I am not sure why this is necessary since it can detect that x is in the orderedset and `found` is still printed

Comment: Could you provide the full traceback? You can [edit] to add it. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Thank you! I added the traceback

Comment: You forgot to put `return` in `__lt__`. It should be `return self.p < other.p`.

Comment: You are right, thank you. In the original code, I don't have the return problem I just forgot it while trying to simplify the code. 
Can you explain why did it pass the if condition maybe it will help with my understanding of the problem?

Comment: For more context, I was using set and sorting it when needed, but this was so slow so I am trying to use sortedset but it's giving me this error

Comment: I don't know why any more than you do. You'd have to read the source code to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class's methods are inconsistent. You have not implemented a full set of comparison methods, or a `__hash__` method. All you have is `__lt__`.

Also, the way you've implemented `__lt__`, as `return self.p < other.p`, implies that as far as your order comparisons are concerned, `example(5, 1)` and `example(5, 2)` are equal (contrary to how your inherited `__eq__` behaves). If you want to be able to store two objects with equal `p` values in the same SortedSet, your comparison operators have to be able to distinguish the two objects.

Because your methods are inconsistent, they report contradictory information to the SortedSet implementation. The hash- and `==`-based parts of the implementation think your objects are different, but the `<`-based parts of the implementation think your objects are equal, and the SortedSet gets very confused.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to `return self.p < other.p`.